# Bind to Page's DataContext

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am finding the need to bind to the `DataContext` of a `Page` which is set like this:

```
<d:Page.DataContext>
    <designTime:PayeesPageDesignViewModel />
</d:Page.DataContext>
```

At design time.  However, I need to bind to it from a child control that has a different data context:

```
<GridView x:Name="PayeesGridView"
          Margin="0,30,0,0"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Payees}"
          SelectionChanged="PayeesGridView_OnSelectionChanged">
```

Since the `ItemsSource` is set for the `GridView`, the `DataContext` of my `GridViewItems` is set to the individual `Payee` objects in the `Payees` collection.  My `ViewModel` has a property that I need to reference from the `View` in a converter to determine the visibility of an item.

I can set the visibility based on a property of the `Payee` object like this:

```
<Border Width="250"
        Height="250"
        Background="Gray"
        Opacity="0.85"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=IsOpen,
                     Converter={StaticResource AccountStatusToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

But what I really need to bind to is the `Settings.ShowInactive` property of the `Page`'s `DataContext`. Is there a way to grab that context from a child control? I am using WinRT, so I don't have the benefit of the `FindAncestor` binding source.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, I tried to change the binding to look like this:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.Settings.ShowInactivePayees, ElementName=PageName,
             Converter={StaticResource AccountStatusToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

But when I set a breakpoint in the `AccountStatusToVisibilityConverter`, the converter is never reached.

Comment: Give the Page an `x:Name` and use an `ElementName` Binding?

Comment: Ah, thanks. I knew there was a way to do it, but I couldn't figure it out. That's what I get for programming in the middle of the night :) I am trying to bind `ElementName="PageName.DataContext"` and `Path="Settings.ShowInactivePayees"` but the being passed is `null` even though the `DesignTimeViewModel` is hard-coded to be `false` and I try at runtime with `ShowInactivePayees` set to `true` or `false`.

Comment: `PageName.DataContext` is not an element name. Your binding should certainly look like `{Binding Path=DataContext.Settings.ShowInactive, ElementName=PageName}`.

Comment: I thought that `ElementName="PageName.DataContext" Path="Settings.ShowInactivePayees"` and `ElementName="PageName" Path="DataContext.Settings.ShowInactivePayees"` were the same? Anyway, I am still getting `null` as the value being passed, regardless of the value of `ShowInactivePayees`.

Comment: I added what the binding looks like now to my question. Now the converter isn't even firing.  I am setting `x:Name="PageName"` and the compiler is recognizing everything, but I don't see why the converter is no longer firing.

Comment: I got it figured out. I was so focused on the `DesignTimeViewModel` that I didn't realize there was no `Settings` property in my regular `ViewModel`, just the underlying `_settings`. @Clemens thanks for your help, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you assigning the ItemTemplate in the GridView?  What if instead of modifying the content of the template you changed the entire template?  Like this pseudo xaml...

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ActiveTemplate"></DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InactiveTemplate"></DataTemplate>
    <local:IsActiveToItemTemplateConverter x:Key="IsActiveToTemplate"
        ActiveTemplate="{StaticResource ActiveTemplate}"
        InactiveTemplate="{StaticResource InactiveTemplate}"
        />
</Page.Resources>

<GridView
    ItemsSoucre="{Binding Payees}"
    ItemTemplate="{Binding Settings.ShowInactive, Converter={StaticResource IsActiveToTemplate}}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="{Binding Settings.ShowInactive, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNot}}"
    />
```

Comment: I like this idea. I will try something like this tonight when I get home from work. Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't realize that I could have separate templates.

Comment: Is there a way to set the `DataContext` of the individual templates? Everything is binding correctly, but ReSharper doesn't like all the unresolved properties.  It thinks that the `DataContext` is the page's context rather than the `ItemsSource` of the `GridView`.

Comment: The items that get created in the list will each have a DataContext of their specific list item...so a "Payee".  There's no way for the app code to modify what object will get assigned as the DataContext because that all happens in GridView's private code.

I think your items should not talk to the Page's DataContext.  This seems like a maintenance issue waiting to bite you.  However, if you must, you could always make each Payee object have a property that points to Page's ViewModel and set that property when you create the Payee objects.  Then you'd have easy access to it inside of an item.

Comment: I think it is fine how it is.. I have the templates defined at the top in the `<Page.Resources>`, which is before the `<GridView>` knows what its `ItemsSource` is going to be.  ReSharper just gets confused because it doesn't know that the templates are going to be associated to a `Payee` object.  I was just looking for something to be able to specify that in the template for auto-complete purposes, and to avoid any squiggly lines from ReSharper :)

Comment: But at runtime, everything works properly with the two different templates. It is just design-time that is an issue because ReSharper can't infer the `DataContext`..

Comment: In that case you might consider making a UserControl to wrap all the content of the DataTemplate.  So your DataTemplate would just have one child and that would be your UserControl.  Then inside your UserControl Xaml you can use the same d: style design time data context specification you're used to.

Comment: Also, if my answers are satisfying could you mark that I've answered the question?  I'm trying to get above 50 reputation so that I can comment on any post.

Comment: Your assistance has been very helpful. Perhaps I will post a new question about using a `UserControl` to achieve what I'm trying to do. Thanks.